# Read One File Then Write to Multiple

Tags: python

**The post marked as duplicate does not answer my question. I asked how to write into multiple files, not read. Also i am asking if i can put all my file names in a variable and call it from there instead of having a lot of with statements.

I am trying to read one file then write to multiple files once i loop through one.

What i want t do is basically open a file, copying a portion of the file (account number until N - NOT BILLED). Then write what i copied into two files. NOTE: I want to loop twice so i can copy one account number until N - NOT BILLED then loop again and copy the next account number until N-NOT BILLED. Also, is there any way i can put all the files i write into a variable. Seems redundant typing 'with open' so many times especially if i have more than two files to write to.

I tried to loop through the account number but its not working for me.

```
account_num = ['1121-17100', '19494-07423']
writing = False

with open('file1.txt', 'r') as original_file:
    with open('CITY OF MIAMI.TXT', 'w') as new_file:
        with open('RICHARD MANAGEMENT.txt', 'w') as new_file2:
            for account in account_num:
                for line in original_file:
                    if account in line.strip():
                        writing = True
                    if writing:
                        new_file.write(line)
                        new_file2.write(line)
                    if 'N - NOT BILLED' in line.strip():
                        writing = False
```

Comment: If you wanted to, you could consolidate your `with` statements into one line, e.g. `with open('f1.txt') as f1, open('f2.txt') as f2, open('f3.txt') as f3: ...`. But more to the point, you should probably swap the two `for` loop positions. The way you have it, the file cursor will terminate before you can get to the next item in `account_num`, so it fails. If you simply swap the order, you should be fine.

Comment: "I tried to loop through the account number but its not working for me." What intended functionality is missing?

Comment: Jordan thank you for your input i will consolidating it. As for swapping the for loops...it actually did work but it duplicated them in both files.

Comment: *"but it duplicated them in both files."*: **What** did you expect if you do `new_file.write(line); new_file2.write(line)`. Your logic are missing a **mapping** between `account` and `filename`. Use a `dict`, e.g. `{'1121-17100':'CITY OF MIAMI.TXT']´}`, instead of `list`

Comment: instead of using new_file.write(line) use a dictionary?

Comment: But still you are not providing a [mcve]. *Not working* is not a proper way to explain your problem.

Comment: I have explained in my previous comments. Its writing to two files and also duplicating each file. I have been told by stovfl its because the line new_file.write(line) and new_file.write(line). If i remove one of them then im back to just one file with duplicating lines.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how to go about inserting contents from account 1121-17100 into CITY OF MIAMI.txt and account 19494-07423 to RICHARD MANAGEMENT.txt